# Seaborn: how to set custom "hue" label in catplot instead of automatic one

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm using seaborn to make nice categorical plots. `seaborn.catplot` helps me a lot.
It uses column names of `pandas.DataFrame` as labels, however sometimes I want to rename these labels on my plots.

It's pretty obvious that I can use `matplotlib.pyplot` to set axes labels, titles and so on. But how can I change hue label? I don't want `ugly_column_name` to display on my plot. I want a different string, may it be `Pretty Category` for instance.

Here is extremely simplified code of my plot, and the resulting image. How do I edit hue label here? Is there a simple one-liner?

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({"ugly_column_name": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
                     "x": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
                     "y": [1, 1.1, 1.5, 1.1, 1.5, 2.0]}
                    )
sns.catplot(x="x", y="y", data=data, hue="ugly_column_name")
plt.xlabel('More than just lowerscore x')
```

[image: catplot sample]

Comment: [Rename the column name in your dataframe.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

Comment: This is not a best way to solve the issue. Label can be long, it can contain special characters and so on. I still need to use the dataframe after plots, and I don't want to type long label as column name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dataframe.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

In your case, add this line(s) to your code:

```
data = data.replace(to_replace="foo", value="foo_alternative")
```

Pleae check the snippet:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({"ugly_column_name": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
                     "x": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
                     "y": [1, 1.1, 1.5, 1.1, 1.5, 2.0]}
                    )

data = data.replace(to_replace="foo", value="foo_alternative")
data = data.replace(to_replace="bar", value="bar_alternative")

sns.catplot(x="x", y="y", data=data, hue="ugly_column_name")
plt.xlabel('More than just lowerscore x')
```

Comment: You got me wrong. I don't need "foo" and "bar" string to be renamed, their names are just fine and are easily changed using your code. But I wanted to rename "ugly_column_name" to "Pretty name". For now I'm using @ImportanceOfBeingErnest solution, but I don't think this is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with Seaborn 0.10.1

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({"ugly_column_name": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
                     "x": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
                     "y": [1, 1.1, 1.5, 1.1, 1.5, 2.0]}
                    )
g = sns.catplot(x="x", y="y", data=data, hue="ugly_column_name")
plt.xlabel('More than just lowerscore x')

# Now change the hue (legend) title
g._legend.set_title('Pretty Category')
```